# Multiple dataframe from dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below from a csv file:

```
aa      |bb     |cc     |dd
1       |2      |3      |4
aa      |bb     |cc     |dd
3       |5      |8      |7
xx      |yy     |zz     |ww
1       |2      |3      |4
xx      |yy     |zz     |ww
2       |4      |5      |6
```

Can I make it into multiple dataframes like below:

```
dataframe name = aa

column_name:    aa      |bb     |cc     |dd
                1       |2      |3      |4
                3       |5      |8      |7

dataframe name = xx

column_name:    xx      |yy     |zz     |ww
                1       |2      |3      |4
                2       |4      |5      |6
```

Comment: It should be far easier to write a python script to fix the csv file (e.g. split it into two files, one for aa, bb, cc and the others for xx, yy, zz) then doing it in pandas

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
df['aa']= df['a'].shift(-1)
df['bb']= df['b'].shift(-1)
df['cc']= df['c'].shift(-1)
df['dd']= df['d'].shift(-1)

df.drop(range(1,len(df),2))
aa=df[lambda x: x['a']=='aa'].drop(['a','b','c','d'],axis=1)
xx=df[lambda x: x['a']=='xx'].drop(['a','b','c','d'],axis=1)
xx.columns= ['xx','yy','zz','ww']
```